# How To Fix This Responsive Navigation Menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-navigation

I have added this navigation menu into My Web Site. But, there is a problem with responsive. When I minimize the web browser , it doesn't fit with the web browser size. And this navigation doesn't fit with mobile phones Or even I can't see a symbol which I can open the Navigation.

[image]

How can I fix this ?? Is there a problem in `@media` screen ?? or in `JS` ??

```js
<script src='//production-assets.codepen.io/assets/common/stopExecutionOnTimeout-b2a7b3fe212eaa732349046d8416e00a9dec26eb7fd347590fbced3ab38af52e.js'></script><script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script>(function($) {
$.fn.menumaker = function(options) {  
 var cssmenu = $(this), settings = $.extend({
   format: "dropdown",
   sticky: false
 }, options);
 return this.each(function() {
   $(this).find(".button").on('click', function(){
     $(this).toggleClass('menu-opened');
     var mainmenu = $(this).next('ul');
     if (mainmenu.hasClass('open')) { 
       mainmenu.slideToggle().removeClass('open');
     }
     else {
       mainmenu.slideToggle().addClass('open');
       if (settings.format === "dropdown") {
         mainmenu.find('ul').show();
       }
     }
   });
   cssmenu.find('li ul').parent().addClass('has-sub');
multiTg = function() {
     cssmenu.find(".has-sub").prepend('<span class="submenu-button"></span>');
     cssmenu.find('.submenu-button').on('click', function() {
       $(this).toggleClass('submenu-opened');
       if ($(this).siblings('ul').hasClass('open')) {
         $(this).siblings('ul').removeClass('open').slideToggle();
       }
       else {
         $(this).siblings('ul').addClass('open').slideToggle();
       }
     });
   };
   if (settings.format === 'multitoggle') multiTg();
   else cssmenu.addClass('dropdown');
   if (settings.sticky === true) cssmenu.css('position', 'fixed');
resizeFix = function() {
  var mediasize = 700;
     if ($( window ).width() > mediasize) {
       cssmenu.find('ul').show();
     }
     if ($(window).width() <= mediasize) {
       cssmenu.find('ul').hide().removeClass('open');
     }
   };
   resizeFix();
   return $(window).on('resize', resizeFix);
 });
  };
})(jQuery);

(function($){
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#cssmenu").menumaker({
   format: "multitoggle"
});
});
})(jQuery);

</script>
```

```css
header
{
position:relative;
z-index:1;
width:100%;
background:#002248;
border-bottom: 3px solid yellow;
border-top: 3px solid yellow;
height:80px;
}

.logo{position:relative;z-index:123;padding:10px;font:18px verdana;color:#6DDB07;float:left;width:15%;margin-right:50px;}
.logo a{color:#6DDB07;}

nav
{

}

#cssmenu,#cssmenu ul,#cssmenu ul li,#cssmenu ul li a,#cssmenu #head-mobile
{

list-style:none;
line-height:1;
display:block;
background-color: #002248;
position:relative;

}

#cssmenu{font-family:sans-serif;background:#333}

#cssmenu > ul > li
{
float:left;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li > a
{
padding:20px;
font-size:12px;
letter-spacing:1px;
text-decoration:none;
color:#ddd;
font-weight:700;
border-right: 1px solid #969696;
}

#cssmenu > ul > li:hover >  a{border-bottom: 3px solid white;}

#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a{padding-right:30px}

#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after{position:absolute;top:22px;right:11px;width:8px;height:2px;display:block;background:#ddd;content:''}

#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before{position:absolute;top:19px;right:14px;display:block;width:2px;height:8px;background:#ddd;content:'';-webkit-transition:all .25s ease;-ms-transition:all .25s ease;transition:all .25s ease}

#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before{top:23px;height:0}

#cssmenu ul ul{position:absolute;left:-9999px}

#cssmenu ul ul li{height:0;-webkit-transition:all .25s ease;-ms-transition:all .25s ease;background:#002248;transition:all .25s ease}

#cssmenu ul ul li:hover{}

#cssmenu li:hover > ul{left:auto}

#cssmenu li:hover > ul > li{height:40px}

#cssmenu ul ul ul{margin-left:100%;top:0}

#cssmenu ul ul li a{border-bottom:1px solid rgba(150,150,150,0.15);padding:11px 15px;width:170px;font-size:12px;text-decoration:none;color:#ddd;font-weight:400;}

#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a,#cssmenu ul ul li.last-item > a{border-bottom:0}

#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,#cssmenu ul ul li a:hover{color:#fff}

#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:after{position:absolute;top:16px;right:11px;width:8px;height:2px;display:block;background:#ddd;content:''}

#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:before{position:absolute;top:13px;right:14px;display:block;width:2px;height:8px;background:#ddd;content:'';-webkit-transition:all .25s ease;-ms-transition:all .25s ease;transition:all .25s ease}

#cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before{top:17px;height:0}

#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub:hover,#cssmenu ul li.has-sub ul li.has-sub ul li:hover{background:#363636;}

#cssmenu ul ul ul li.active a{border-left:1px solid #333}

#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > ul > li.active > a,#cssmenu > ul ul > li.has-sub > ul > li.active> a{border-top:1px solid #333}

@media screen and (max-width:700px){
.logo{position:absolute;top:0;left: 0;width:100%;height:46px;text-align:center;padding:10px 0 0 0 ;float:none}
.logo2{display:none}
nav{width:100%;}
#cssmenu{width:100%}
#cssmenu ul{width:100%;display:none}
#cssmenu ul li{width:100%;border-top:1px solid #444}
#cssmenu ul li:hover{background:#363636;}
#cssmenu ul ul li,#cssmenu li:hover > ul > li{height:auto}
#cssmenu ul li a,#cssmenu ul ul li a{width:100%;border-bottom:0}
#cssmenu > ul > li{float:none}
#cssmenu ul ul li a{padding-left:25px}
#cssmenu ul ul li{background:#333!important;}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover{background:#363636!important}
#cssmenu ul ul ul li a{padding-left:35px}
#cssmenu ul ul li a{color:#ddd;background:none}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,#cssmenu ul ul li.active > a{color:#fff}
#cssmenu ul ul,#cssmenu ul ul ul{position:relative;left:0;width:100%;margin:0;text-align:left}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after,#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before,#cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub > a:after,#cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub > a:before{display:none}
#cssmenu #head-mobile{display:block;padding:23px;color:#ddd;font-size:12px;font-weight:700}
.button{width:55px;height:46px;position:absolute;right:0;top:0;cursor:pointer;z-index: 12399994;}
.button:after{position:absolute;top:22px;right:20px;display:block;height:4px;width:20px;border-top:2px solid #dddddd;border-bottom:2px solid #dddddd;content:''}
.button:before{-webkit-transition:all .3s ease;-ms-transition:all .3s ease;transition:all .3s ease;position:absolute;top:16px;right:20px;display:block;height:2px;width:20px;background:#ddd;content:''}
.button.menu-opened:after{-webkit-transition:all .3s ease;-ms-transition:all .3s ease;transition:all .3s ease;top:23px;border:0;height:2px;width:19px;background:#fff;-webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);-moz-transform:rotate(45deg);-ms-transform:rotate(45deg);-o-transform:rotate(45deg);transform:rotate(45deg)}
.button.menu-opened:before{top:23px;background:#fff;width:19px;-webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);-moz-transform:rotate(-45deg);-ms-transform:rotate(-45deg);-o-transform:rotate(-45deg);transform:rotate(-45deg)}
#cssmenu .submenu-button{position:absolute;z-index:99;right:0;top:0;display:block;border-left:1px solid #444;height:46px;width:46px;cursor:pointer}
#cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened{background:#262626}
#cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button{height:34px;width:34px}
#cssmenu .submenu-button:after{position:absolute;top:22px;right:19px;width:8px;height:2px;display:block;background:#ddd;content:''}
#cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button:after{top:15px;right:13px}
#cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened:after{background:#fff}
#cssmenu .submenu-button:before{position:absolute;top:19px;right:22px;display:block;width:2px;height:8px;background:#ddd;content:''}
#cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button:before{top:12px;right:16px}
#cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened:before{display:none}
#cssmenu ul ul ul li.active a{border-left:none}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > ul > li.active > a,#cssmenu > ul ul > li.has-sub > ul > li.active > a{border-top:none}
}
```

```html
<header>

<div class="logo">
<a href="index.php"><img src="img/WisdomName.png" id="logo" align="left" height="50" width="200" style="margin-left:40px;margin-top:0px;" /></img></a>
</div>

<nav id='cssmenu'>

<ul>
<li class='active'><a href='#'>HOME</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>ABOUT</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>PRODUCTS</a>
   <ul>
      <li><a href='#'>Product 1</a>
         <ul>
            <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href='#'>Product 2</a>
         <ul>
            <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Sub Product</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</li>
<li><a href='#'>BIO</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>VIDEO</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>GALLERY</a></li>
<li><a href='#'>CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>

</nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Do you have `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` in your `<head>`?

Comment: @Darren - Yes..
How can I fix this problem ??

Comment: You probably want to simplify your code first. Use classes on your elements, which will make your CSS much easier to write and you can use class selector instead of `#cssmenu > ul ul > li.has-sub > ul > li.active> a`. And please post [minimal, complete, and verifiable code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Darren - Okay , Thank U !!